# Connect to a NuGet feed on Azure Devops 2019 from VS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to connect to my Azure Devops 2019 NuGet feed from the package manager in Visual Studio 2019. I have added the source https://myurl/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json but when I try to connect to it in VS I get the following error:

Unable to load the service index for source `https://myurl/tfs/DefaultCollection/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/index.json.   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`

I followed the instructions here regarding the PAT security token but I am not sure how to use the PAT in VS.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/nuget-exe?view=azdevops&tabs=new-nav

How can I use the VS package manager with Azure Devops artifacts?

Comment: so after nuget add source nuget restore from cmd is working as expected?

Comment: Hi @FalcoAlexander the restore command is working properly from cmd. But I am unable to connect to the feed within VS.

Comment: for me it works very fine from VS. but it seems it relies on some token cached when logged in...? what happens when you open your feed's url in a anonymous browser session?

Comment: You don't need the PAT with VS since 2015 (windows).

Comment: Hi @FalcoAlexander thanks for the suggestions. It turns out this works fine in VS2015 where I was prompted for a password. In VS2017 I was not prompet for password. Do you know how I can force it, maybe by clearing some VS specific user settings?

Comment: Ok, it works now both in VS2017 and VS2015. I only tried it in VS2015 and after that it worked in 2017 as well.

Comment: glad, I could help, but no kudos for me 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Connect to a NuGet feed on Azure Devops 2019 from VS

Just as Falco said, you don not need the PAT with Visual Studio, because that is used for nuget.exe CLI.

When you connect the Azure Devops 2019 NuGet feed with Visual Studio, Visual Studio will prompt you to log in to your personal credential:

[image]

According to the error message 401 (Unauthorized), it seems you do not log in Visual Studio with a valid personal credential, to resolve this issue, please try to logout your current account and restart Visual Studio, then reopen Visual Studio, select the Azure Devops 2019 NuGet feed, Visual Studio will prompt you to log in to your personal credential again:

[image]

**Enter the valid personal credential and make sure this personal credential that can access your Azure Devops 2019 NuGet feed**.

Besides, we could also to provide credentials to Visual Studio manually with `nuget.config` under the folder `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="AzureDevOpsFeed" value="<ThePackageSourceFeedUrl>/MyCustomFeed/nuget/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>


  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <AzureDevOpsFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="<YourUserName>" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="<YourPassword>" />
    </AzureDevOpsFeed>
</configuration>
```

Check [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54183445/accessing-azure-devops-package-feed-with-azure-ad-work-account/54194316#54194316) thread for some more details.
Hope this helps.

Comment: so where does VS save the credentials? I guess it will use the same set or token as the team explorer when connected to VSTS?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander, Yes, you are right.  It use the same set as the team explorer when connected to VSTS. When you log in Visual Studio and connect to the feed with credentials, Visual Studio will verify the credential and save it in the Visual Studio with login credentials